# How to validate form fields in server side Spring MVC with one to many Hibernate mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am doing registration using Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have two model classes i.e. parent and student with hibernate one to many mapping. The registration JSP page contains both student and parent fields. 

 How to validate both fields in server side and how to display error in JSP near the textbox? 
 
I don't know to how to write spring form and to use ModelAttribute in JSP mapping to controller for this. I have used just html form. 
In below validator class am trying to validate

```
<form id="studentEnrollmentForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="saveStudentByAdmin">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Full Name</label>
                                            <div class="group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentFirstName" id="fn" placeholder="First name" />
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentLastName"  placeholder="Last name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Parents Full Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentFirstName" placeholder="First name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentLastName" placeholder="Last name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
                                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">
                                                    <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="studentDOB" /> <span
                                                        class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
                                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                    <label class="btn btn-default"> 
                                                    <input type="radio" name="studentGender" value="male" />Male</label>
                                                     <label class="btn btn-default"> 
                                                     <input type="radio" name="studentGender" value="female" />Female</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Phone</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentPhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number" />
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parentEmail" placeholder="Email" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>




                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Permanent Address</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="studentPermanentAddress" /></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Present Address</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="studentPresentAddress" /></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Class to join</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <!--    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="className" placeholder="Enter Class" /> -->
                                            <select name="className" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="">Select class </option>
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>                                                  
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="rstbutton">Refresh</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AdminRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private IAdminRegistrationService  adminRegistrationService;    

    @Autowired
    private StudentRegistrationFromAdminValidator  studentRegistrationFromAdminValidator;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String viewRegistrationPage(Model model) {
         StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO();
         ParentDTO pdto=new ParentDTO();
            model.addAttribute("teacherDTO", studentDTO);
            model.addAttribute("teacherDTO", pdto);
            return "StudentEnrollmentByAdmin";
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStudentByAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTeacherByAdmin(@Valid @ModelAttribute StudentDTO sdto,@ModelAttribute ParentDTO pdto,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {  



         if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                System.out.println(bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
             }


        return "redirect:/register"; // this line redirecting to above method to avoid same data insertion again when i press f5
        //return "TeacherEnrollmentByAdmin"; To know duplication insertion comment above line and above method current this line
        //when you get response page(after insertion of data) press f5 and see in data base
    }
}
```

**Validator class**

```
@Component
public class StudentRegistrationFromAdminValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return StudentDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
        //return ParentDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        StudentDTO student = (StudentDTO)target;
        ParentDTO parent = (ParentDTO)target;       
        String studentFirstName = student.getStudentFirstName();
        String parentFirstName=parent.getParentFirstName();     
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "studentFirstName", "student.studentFirstName.empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "parentFirstName", "parent.parentFirstName.empty");       
        if(studentFirstName.equals("pradee")){
            errors.rejectValue("studentFirstName", "student.studentFirstName.invalid");
        }           
        if(parentFirstName.equals("pradee")){
            errors.rejectValue("parentFirstName", "parent.parentFirstName.invalid");
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the model classes??

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side form validation in Spring MVC with hibernate. Hibernate has hibernate validator with many annotations. In order to use it, attributes of the model class must be annotated.

Spring MVC provides full support for bean validation. It will validate the model object annotated by **@Valid** annotation after binding its properties with inputs from JSP form that uses Spring's form tags.

Since you are using annotation based Spring MVC. Why not validate using annotations. Here is what i did for this problem.

Modified JSP using form tags:

```
<form:form id="studentEnrollmentForm" method="post"
    class="form-horizontal" action="/saveStudentByAdmin"
    modelAttribute="student">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Full Name</label>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="firstName"
                    placeholder="First name" />
                    <!-- errors will display here -->
                    <form:errors path="firstName" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="middleName"
                placeholder="Middle name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="lastName"
                placeholder="Last name" />
                <form:errors path="lastName" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Parents Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="parent.firstName"
                placeholder="First name" />
                <form:errors path="parent.firstName" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control"
                path="parent.middleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="parent.lastName"
                placeholder="Last name" />
                <form:errors path="parent.lastName" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3 ">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">
                <form:input type="Text" class="form-control" path="DOB" />
                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default"> <form:radiobutton
                        path="gender" value="male" />Male
                </label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <form:radiobutton
                        path="gender" value="female" />Female
                </label>
                <form:errors path="gender" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control"
                path="parent.phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone number" />
                <form:errors path="parent.phoneNumber" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="parent.email"
                placeholder="Email" />
                <form:errors path="parent.email" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Permanent Address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:textarea class="form-control" rows="3" path="permanentAddress" />
            <form:errors path="permanentAddress" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Present Address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:textarea class="form-control" rows="3" path="presentAddress" />
            <form:errors path="presentAddress" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Class to join</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <form:select path="className" class="form-control">
                <form:option value="" label="Select class"></form:option>
                <form:options items="${classNames}" />
            </form:select>
            <form:errors path="className" cssStyle="color : red;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1 ">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 ">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="rstbutton">Refresh</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

**Student Class:**

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your first name.")
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your last name.")
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter date of birth.")
    private String DOB;
    @NotNull
    private String gender;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your permanent address.")
    private String permanentAddress;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your present address.")
    private String presentAddress;
    @Range(min = 1, max=10, message = "class must be between 1 to 10")
    private String className;
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;
    ... //All getters and setters;
}
```

**Parent Class:**

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter parent first name.")
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Parent first name is required.")
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "phone number must be filled.")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Email(message = "Email is not valid.")
    private String email;
    ... //All getters and setters;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AdminRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private IAdminRegistrationService adminRegistrationService;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRegistrationFromAdminValidator studentRegistrationFromAdminValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistrationPage(Model model) {
        StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO();
        ParentDTO pdto = new ParentDTO();
        model.addAttribute("teacherDTO", studentDTO);
        model.addAttribute("teacherDTO", pdto);
        return "StudentEnrollmentByAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String displayRegistrationForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("classNames", new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" });
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        return "registration"; // return registration jsp
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStudentByAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTeacherByAdmin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student")    Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()
            return "registration"; //it returns the error messages to the same page
        }
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your mail id

Comment: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: What is the exact error? It runs fine in my computer.

Comment: am very much struggling here

Comment: Go through the link https://github.com/mesurace/Spring_MVC_Server_Side_Form_Validation